# Buttons expanding after curtain added

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add sliding curtains/doors to the buttons, without the buttons expanding.

The curtains on the buttons are supposed to work the same way the other ones do.

How would I fix that?

How it works is, you click on the buttons and they open up.

The play image that holds the buttons is the orange one. **.playc**

Curtain **added** to buttons
https://jsfiddle.net/5Lycdb4u/

[image]

Curtain **removed** from buttons https://jsfiddle.net/fcpvs9aq/3/

[image: https://i.imgur.com/gNMrDYR.png]

```js
const manageCover = (function makeManageCover() {
  const config = {};

  function show(el) {
    el.classList.remove("hide");
  }

  function hide(el) {
    el.classList.add("hide");
  }

  function hideAll(elements) {
    elements.forEach(hide);
  }

  function showCovers(playButton) {
    const cover = playButton.parentElement;
    cover.classList.add("active");
    show(cover);
  }

  function coverClickHandler(evt) {
    hideAll(config.containers);
    const cover = evt.currentTarget;
    showCovers(cover);
  }

  function addClickToButtons(playButtons) {
    playButtons.forEach(function addEventHandler(playButton) {
      playButton.addEventListener("click", coverClickHandler);
    });
  }

  function addCoverHandler(coverSelector, handler) {
    const cover = document.querySelector(coverSelector);
    cover.addEventListener("click", handler);
  }

  function init(selectors) {
    config.containers = document.querySelectorAll(selectors.container);
    const playButtons = document.querySelectorAll(selectors.playButton);
    addClickToButtons(playButtons);
  }

  return {
    addCoverHandler,
    init,
    show
  };
}());


const videoPlayer = (function makeVideoPlayer() {
  const players = [];

  const tag = document.createElement("script");
  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/player_api";
  const firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  function onPlayerReady(event) {
    const player = event.target;
    player.setVolume(100);
  }

  function addPlayer(video, settings, videoIds = video.dataset.id) {
    const videoId = !Array.isArray(videoIds) && videoIds;
    const playlist = Array.isArray(videoIds) && videoIds;
    const config = {
      host: "https://www.youtube-nocookie.com",
      videoId
    };
    config.playerVars = {
      playlist: playlist || undefined
    };

    config.events = {
      "onReady": onPlayerReady
    };
    const defaultOptions = config;
    const playerOptions = Object.assign({}, defaultOptions, settings);
    players.push(new YT.Player(video, playerOptions));
  }

  return {
    addPlayer
  };
}());


const managePlayer = (function makeManagePlayer() {
  const config = {
    height: 600,
    width: 360
  };
  config.playerVars = {
    autoplay: 0,
    controls: 1,
    disablekb: 1,
    enablejsapi: 1,
    fs: 0,
    iv_load_policy: 3,
    rel: 0
  };

  function show(el) {
    el.classList.remove("hide");
  }

  function createPlayerOptions(settings) {
    function paramInOptions(opts, param) {
      if (settings[param] !== undefined) {
        opts[param] = settings[param];
        delete settings[param];
      }
      return opts;
    }

    const optionParams = ["width", "height", "playlist", "host", "videoid"];
    const defaultOptions = config;
    const preferred = optionParams.reduce(paramInOptions, {});
    const playerOptions = Object.assign({}, defaultOptions, preferred);
    // settings should now only consist of playerVars
    const playerVars = Object.assign({}, config, settings);
    config.playerVars = Object.assign({}, config, playerVars);
    return config;
  }

  function createPlayer(videoWrapper, settings = {}, videoIds = "") {
    const video = videoWrapper.querySelector(".video");
    if (!videoIds) {
      videoIds = video.dataset.id;
    }
    const playerOptions = createPlayerOptions(settings);
    return videoPlayer.addPlayer(video, playerOptions, videoIds);
  }

  function createCoverClickHandler(playerSettings, videoIds) {
    return function coverClickHandler(evt) {
      const cover = evt.currentTarget;
      const wrapper = cover.nextElementSibling;
      show(wrapper);
      const player = createPlayer(wrapper, playerSettings, videoIds);
      wrapper.player = player;
    };
  }

  function addPlayer(coverSelector, playerSettings, videoIds) {
    const clickHandler = createCoverClickHandler(playerSettings, videoIds);
    manageCover.addCoverHandler(coverSelector, clickHandler);
  }

  function addPlayerRandomVideo(coverSelector, playerSettings, videoIds) {
    const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * videoIds.length);
    const videoId = videoIds[index];
    const clickHandler = createCoverClickHandler(playerSettings, videoId);
    manageCover.addCoverHandler(coverSelector, clickHandler);
  }

  function init(playerOptions) {
    Object.assign(config, playerOptions);
  }

  return {
    add: addPlayer,
    addRandom: addPlayerRandomVideo,
    init
  };
}());


function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  managePlayer.init({
    playerVars: {
      autoplay: 0
    }
  });
  managePlayer.addRandom(".playa", {
    height: 207,
    start: 45,
    width: 277
  }, [
    "0dgNc5S8cLI",
    "mnfmQe8Mv1g",
    "-Xgi_way56U",
    "CHahce95B1g"
  ]);
  managePlayer.add(".playb", {
    height: 207,
    width: 277
  });
  manageCover.init({
    container: ".container",
    playButton: ".thePlay"
  });
}


(function initPlayButtons() {
  function getButtonContainer(el) {
    while (el.classList.contains("playButton") === false) {
      el = el.parentNode;
    }
    return el;
  }

  function getPlay(button) {
    return button;
  }

  function showPlayButton(button) {
    button.classList.remove("active");
  }

  function isPlaying(button) {
    const play = getPlay(button);
    return play.classList.contains("active");
  }

  function pauseAllButtons() {
    let buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".playButton");
    buttons.forEach(function hidePause(buttons) {
      if (isPlaying(buttons)) {
        showPlayButton(buttons);
      }
    });
  }

  function showPauseButton(button) {
    pauseAllButtons();
    button.classList.add("active");
  }

  function getAudio() {
    return document.querySelector("audio");
  }

  function playAudio(player, src) {
    player.volume = 1.0;
    if (player.getAttribute("src") !== src) {
      player.setAttribute("src", src);
    }
    player.play();
  }

  function showButton(button, opts) {
    if (opts.playing) {
      showPlayButton(button);
    } else {
      showPauseButton(button);
    }
  }

  function pauseAudio(player) {
    player.pause();
  }

  function manageAudio(player, opts) {
    if (opts.playing) {
      pauseAudio(player);
    } else {
      playAudio(player, opts.src);
    }
  }

  function playButton(button) {
    const player = getAudio();
    const playing = isPlaying(button);
    showButton(button, {
      playing
    });
    manageAudio(player, {
      playing,
      src: button.getAttribute("data-audio")
    });
  }

  function playButtonClickHandler(evt) {
    const button = getButtonContainer(evt.target);
    playButton(button);
  }

  const playButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".button");
  playButtons.forEach(function addHandler(el) {
    el.addEventListener("click", playButtonClickHandler);
  });
})();
```

```css
$color: #ff1818;
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: #353198;
  animation: fade 2s ease 0s forwards;
}

@keyframes fade {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.outer {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container.active {
  flex: 1 0 0;
  animation: fadebody 5s ease 0s forwards;
  background-size: 165px 165px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(teal 5px, #0000 5px), linear-gradient(90deg, teal 5px, #0000 5px), linear-gradient(black 10px, #0000 10px 160px, black 160px), linear-gradient(90deg, black 10px, #0000 10px 160px, black 160px), linear-gradient(orange 15px, #0000 15px 155px, orange 155px), linear-gradient(90deg, orange 15px, #0000 15px 155px, orange 155px), linear-gradient(black 20px, #0000 20px 150px, black 150px), linear-gradient(90deg, black 20px, #0000 20px 150px, black 150px), linear-gradient(teal 25px, #0000 25px 145px, teal 145px), linear-gradient(90deg, teal 25px, #0000 25px 145px, teal 145px), linear-gradient(black 30px, #0000 30px 140px, black 140px), linear-gradient(90deg, black 30px, #0000 30px 140px, black 140px), linear-gradient(orange 35px, #0000 35px 135px, orange 135px), linear-gradient(90deg, orange 35px, #0000 35px 135px, orange 135px), linear-gradient(black 40px, #0000 40px 130px, black 130px), linear-gradient(90deg, black 40px, #0000 40px 130px, black 130px), linear-gradient(teal 45px, #0000 45px 125px, teal 125px), linear-gradient(90deg, teal 45px, #0000 45px 125px, teal 125px), linear-gradient(black 50px, #0000 50px 120px, black 120px), linear-gradient(90deg, black 50px, #0000 50px 120px, black 120px), linear-gradient(orange 55px, #0000 55px 115px, orange 115px), linear-gradient(90deg, orange 55px, #0000 55px 115px, orange 115px), linear-gradient(black 60px, #0000 60px 110px, black 110px), linear-gradient(90deg, black 60px, #0000 60px 110px, black 110px), linear-gradient(teal 65px, #0000 65px 105px, teal 105px), linear-gradient(90deg, teal 65px, #0000 65px 105px, teal 105px), linear-gradient(black 70px, #0000 70px 100px, black 100px), linear-gradient(90deg, black 70px, #0000 70px 100px, black 100px), linear-gradient(orange 75px, #0000 75px 95px, orange 95px), linear-gradient(90deg, orange 75px, #0000 75px 95px, orange 95px), linear-gradient(black 80px, #0000 80px 90px, black 90px), linear-gradient(90deg, black 80px, #0000 80px 90px, black 90px), linear-gradient(teal, teal);
}


/* when container is active hide the svg */

.container.active .thePlay {
  display: none;
}

.button-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: auto;
  width: 582px;
  min-width: 582px;
  overflow: hidden
}

.inner-container {
  display: none;
}


/* when container is active hide the svg and show the inner container*/

.container.active .thePlay {
  display: none;
}

.container.active .inner-container {
  display: flex;
}

.container.active .inner-container.curtain {
  display: block;
}

@keyframes fadebody {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.playa,
.playb,
.playc {
  margin: auto 20px;
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.playa {
  fill: red;
  filter: drop-shadow(3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7));
}

.playb {
  fill: blue;
  filter: drop-shadow(3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7));
}

.playc {
  fill: orange;
  filter: drop-shadow(3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7));
}

.curtain {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 640px;
  margin: auto;
  flex: 1 0 0%;
}

.panel-left,
.panel-right {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: calc(50% + 1px);
  /* rounding error fix */
  top: 0%;
  transition: all ease 10s;
  /*background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/600");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;*/
  overflow: hidden;
}

.panel-left {
  left: 0;
  /*background-color: rgb(91, 96, 106);*/
}

.panel-right {
  right: 0;
  /*background-color: rgb(229, 211, 211);*/
}

.panel-left::before,
.panel-right::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 200%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/id/26/1920/1080");
  background-size: auto;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0 0;
}

.curtain2 .panel-left::before,
.curtain2 .panel-right::before {
  background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/id/27/1920/1080");
}

.curtain3 .panel-left::before,
.curtain3 .panel-right::before {
  background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/id/27/1920/1080");
}

.panel-right::before {
  left: -100%;
}

.container.active .curtain .panel-left {
  animation: curtain1 8s forwards;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

@keyframes curtain1 {
  to {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}

.container.active .curtain .panel-right {
  animation: curtain2 8s forwards;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

@keyframes curtain2 {
  to {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}

@keyframes curtain3 {
  to {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}

.ratio-keeper {
  position: relative;
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 56.25%;
  border-radius: 25px;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.video-frame {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.playButton {
  position: relative;
  background-color: black;
  /*width: 150px; /* delete */
  margin: 2px;
  height: 195px;
  flex: 0 0 150px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 0 1px 2px black, inset 0 2px 2px -2px white, inset 0 0 2px 15px #47434c, inset 0 0 2px 22px black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 20px;
  perspective: 700px;
}

.playButton.active .button {
  transform: translateZ(20px) rotateX(25deg);
  box-shadow: 0 -10px 20px $color;
}

.playButton.active .button .light {
  animation: flicker 0.2s infinite 0.3s;
}

.playButton.active .button .shine {
  opacity: 1;
}

.playButton.active .button .shadow {
  opacity: 0;
}

.playButton .button {
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(1, 0, 1, 1);
  transform-origin: center center -20px;
  transform: translateZ(20px) rotateX(-25deg);
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  background-color: #9b0621;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: linear-gradient( darken($color, 25%) 0%, darken($color, 33%) 30%, darken($color, 33%) 70%, darken($color, 25%) 100%);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.playButton .button::before {
  content: "";
  background: linear-gradient( rgba(white, 0.8) 10%, rgba(white, 0.3) 30%, darken($color, 35%) 75%, darken($color, 45%)) 50% 50% / 97% 97%, darken($color, 20%);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  transform-origin: top;
  transform: rotateX(-90deg);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.playButton .button::after {
  content: "";
  background-image: linear-gradient(darken($color, 35%), darken($color, 45%));
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  transform-origin: top;
  transform: translateY(50px) rotateX(-90deg);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 50px 8px 0px black, 0 80px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.playButton .light {
  opacity: 0;
  animation: light-off 1s;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: radial-gradient( adjust-hue(lighten($color, 20%), 35), $color 40%, transparent 70%);
}

.playButton .dots {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: radial-gradient( transparent 30%, rgba(darken($color, 35%), 0.7) 70%);
  background-size: 10px 10px;
}

.playButton .characters {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(white, white) 50% 20%/5% 20%, radial-gradient( circle, transparent 50%, white 52%, white 70%, transparent 72%) 50% 80%/33% 25%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.playButton .shine {
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(1, 0, 1, 1);
  opacity: 0.3;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(white, transparent 3%) 50% 50%/97% 97%, linear-gradient( rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), transparent 50%, transparent 80%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)) 50% 50%/97% 97%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.playButton .shadow {
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(1, 0, 1, 1);
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(transparent 70%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8));
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

@keyframes flicker {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 0.8;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes light-off {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<audio></audio>

<div class="outer">

  <div class="container with-curtain">
    <svg class="playa thePlay" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
            <path d="M25.6,46.4L44.8,32L25.6,17.6V46.4z M32,0C14.3,0,0,14.3,0,32s14.3,32,32,32s32-14.3,32-32S49.7,0,32,0z
      M32,57.6C17.9,57.6,6.4,46.1,6.4,32S17.9,6.4,32,6.4S57.6,17.9,57.6,32S46.1,57.6,32,57.6z" />
        </svg>
    
    <div class="inner-container curtain curtain1">
      <div class="ratio-keeper">
        <div class="wrapa">
          <div class="video video-frame"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-left"></div>
        <div class="panel-right"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container with-curtain">
    <svg class="playb thePlay " width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
            <path d="M25.6,46.4L44.8,32L25.6,17.6V46.4z M32,0C14.3,0,0,14.3,0,32s14.3,32,32,32s32-14.3,32-32S49.7,0,32,0z
      M32,57.6C17.9,57.6,6.4,46.1,6.4,32S17.9,6.4,32,6.4S57.6,17.9,57.6,32S46.1,57.6,32,57.6z" />
        </svg>
    
    <div class="inner-container curtain curtain2">
      <div class="ratio-keeper">
        <div class="wrapb">
          <div class="video video-frame" data-id="2VwsvrPFr9w"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-left"></div>
        <div class="panel-right"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container with-buttons">
    <svg class="playc thePlay" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
      <path d="M25.6,46.4L44.8,32L25.6,17.6V46.4z M32,0C14.3,0,0,14.3,0,32s14.3,32,32,32s32-14.3,32-32S49.7,0,32,0z
      M32,57.6C17.9,57.6,6.4,46.1,6.4,32S17.9,6.4,32,6.4S57.6,17.9,57.6,32S46.1,57.6,32,57.6z" />
    </svg>
    
    <div class="inner-container button-container curtain curtain3">
      <div class="playButton b1" data-audio="http://getradio.me/svoefm">
        <div class="button">
          <div class="light"></div>
          <div class="dots"></div>
          <div class="characters"></div>
          <div class="shine"></div>
          <div class="shadow"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="playButton b2" data-audio="ttp:/fm1.hostingradio.ru:14536/rock90.mp3">
        <div class="button">
          <div class="light"></div>
          <div class="dots"></div>
          <div class="characters"></div>
          <div class="shine"></div>
          <div class="shadow"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="playButton b3" data-audio="http:/fm1.hostingradio.ru:14536/rock90.mp3">
        <div class="button">
          <div class="light"></div>
          <div class="dots"></div>
          <div class="characters"></div>
          <div class="shine"></div>
          <div class="shadow"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="playButton b4" data-audio="http:/fm1.hostingradio.ru:14536/rock90.mp3">
        <div class="button">
          <div class="light"></div>
          <div class="dots"></div>
          <div class="characters"></div>
          <div class="shine"></div>
          <div class="shadow"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="playButton b5" data-audio="http:/fm1.hostingradio.ru:14536/rock90.mp3">
        <div class="button">
          <div class="light"></div>
          <div class="dots"></div>
          <div class="characters"></div>
          <div class="shine"></div>
          <div class="shadow"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="playButton b6" data-audio="http:/fm1.hostingradio.ru:14536/rock90.mp3">
        <div class="button">
          <div class="light"></div>
          <div class="dots"></div>
          <div class="characters"></div>
          <div class="shine"></div>
          <div class="shadow"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="playButton b7" data-audio="http:/fm1.hostingradio.ru:14536/rock90.mp3">
        <div class="button">
          <div class="light"></div>
          <div class="dots"></div>
          <div class="characters"></div>
          <div class="shine"></div>
          <div class="shadow"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="playButton b8" data-audio="http:/fm1.hostingradio.ru:14536/rock90.mp3">
        <div class="button">
          <div class="light"></div>
          <div class="dots"></div>
          <div class="characters"></div>
          <div class="shine"></div>
          <div class="shadow"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="playButton b9" data-audio="http:/fm1.hostingradio.ru:14536/rock90.mp3">
        <div class="button">
          <div class="light"></div>
          <div class="dots"></div>
          <div class="characters"></div>
          <div class="shine"></div>
          <div class="shadow"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-left"></div>
      <div class="panel-right"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```css
.container.active .inner-container.curtain {
  display: block;
}
```

But it has to be `display: flex;` for `.container.with-buttons.active`. Therefor you could add the following after the statement above:

```css
.container.with-buttons.active .inner-container.curtain {
  display: flex;
}
```

To align the curtain you also have to set the `flex` property to `none`:

```css
.container.with-buttons .curtain {
  flex: none;
}
```

**Working example:**

```js
const manageCover = (function makeManageCover() {
  const config = {};

  function show(el) {
    el.classList.remove("hide");
  }

  function hide(el) {
    el.classList.add("hide");
  }

  function hideAll(elements) {
    elements.forEach(hide);
  }

  function showCovers(playButton) {
    const cover = playButton.parentElement;
    cover.classList.add("active");
    show(cover);
  }

  function coverClickHandler(evt) {
    hideAll(config.containers);
    const cover = evt.currentTarget;
    showCovers(cover);
  }

  function addClickToButtons(playButtons) {
    playButtons.forEach(function addEventHandler(playButton) {
      playButton.addEventListener("click", coverClickHandler);
    });
  }

  function addCoverHandler(coverSelector, handler) {
    const cover = document.querySelector(coverSelector);
    cover.addEventListener("click", handler);
  }

  function init(selectors) {
    config.containers = document.querySelectorAll(selectors.container);
    const playButtons = document.querySelectorAll(selectors.playButton);
    addClickToButtons(playButtons);
  }

  return {
    addCoverHandler,
    init,
    show
  };
}());


const videoPlayer = (function makeVideoPlayer() {
  const players = [];

  const tag = document.createElement("script");
  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/player_api";
  const firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  function onPlayerReady(event) {
    const player = event.target;
    player.setVolume(100);
  }

  function addPlayer(video, settings, videoIds = video.dataset.id) {
    const videoId = !Array.isArray(videoIds) && videoIds;
    const playlist = Array.isArray(videoIds) && videoIds;
    const config = {
      host: "https://www.youtube-nocookie.com",
      videoId
    };
    config.playerVars = {
      playlist: playlist || undefined
    };

    config.events = {
      "onReady": onPlayerReady
    };
    const defaultOptions = config;
    const playerOptions = Object.assign({}, defaultOptions, settings);
    players.push(new YT.Player(video, playerOptions));
  }

  return {
    addPlayer
  };
}());


const managePlayer = (function makeManagePlayer() {
  const config = {
    height: 600,
    width: 360
  };
  config.playerVars = {
    autoplay: 0,
    controls: 1,
    disablekb: 1,
    enablejsapi: 1,
    fs: 0,
    iv_load_policy: 3,
    rel: 0
  };

  function show(el) {
    el.classList.remove("hide");
  }

  function createPlayerOptions(settings) {
    function paramInOptions(opts, param) {
      if (settings[param] !== undefined) {
        opts[param] = settings[param];
        delete settings[param];
      }
      return opts;
    }

    const optionParams = ["width", "height", "playlist", "host", "videoid"];
    const defaultOptions = config;
    const preferred = optionParams.reduce(paramInOptions, {});
    const playerOptions = Object.assign({}, defaultOptions, preferred);
    // settings should now only consist of playerVars
    const playerVars = Object.assign({}, config, settings);
    config.playerVars = Object.assign({}, config, playerVars);
    return config;
  }

  function createPlayer(videoWrapper, settings = {}, videoIds = "") {
    const video = videoWrapper.querySelector(".video");
    if (!videoIds) {
      videoIds = video.dataset.id;
    }
    const playerOptions = createPlayerOptions(settings);
    return videoPlayer.addPlayer(video, playerOptions, videoIds);
  }

  function createCoverClickHandler(playerSettings, videoIds) {
    return function coverClickHandler(evt) {
      const cover = evt.currentTarget;
      const wrapper = cover.nextElementSibling;
      show(wrapper);
      const player = createPlayer(wrapper, playerSettings, videoIds);
      wrapper.player = player;
    };
  }

  function addPlayer(coverSelector, playerSettings, videoIds) {
    const clickHandler = createCoverClickHandler(playerSettings, videoIds);
    manageCover.addCoverHandler(coverSelector, clickHandler);
  }

  function addPlayerRandomVideo(coverSelector, playerSettings, videoIds) {
    const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * videoIds.length);
    const videoId = videoIds[index];
    const clickHandler = createCoverClickHandler(playerSettings, videoId);
    manageCover.addCoverHandler(coverSelector, clickHandler);
  }

  function init(playerOptions) {
    Object.assign(config, playerOptions);
  }

  return {
    add: addPlayer,
    addRandom: addPlayerRandomVideo,
    init
  };
}());


function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  managePlayer.init({
    playerVars: {
      autoplay: 0
    }
  });
  managePlayer.addRandom(".playa", {
    height: 207,
    start: 45,
    width: 277
  }, [
    "0dgNc5S8cLI",
    "mnfmQe8Mv1g",
    "-Xgi_way56U",
    "CHahce95B1g"
  ]);
  managePlayer.add(".playb", {
    height: 207,
    width: 277
  });
  manageCover.init({
    container: ".container",
    playButton: ".thePlay"
  });
}


(function initPlayButtons() {
  function getButtonContainer(el) {
    while (el.classList.contains("playButton") === false) {
      el = el.parentNode;
    }
    return el;
  }

  function getPlay(button) {
    return button;
  }

  function showPlayButton(button) {
    button.classList.remove("active");
  }

  function isPlaying(button) {
    const play = getPlay(button);
    return play.classList.contains("active");
  }

  function pauseAllButtons() {
    let buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".playButton");
    buttons.forEach(function hidePause(buttons) {
      if (isPlaying(buttons)) {
        showPlayButton(buttons);
      }
    });
  }

  function showPauseButton(button) {
    pauseAllButtons();
    button.classList.add("active");
  }

  function getAudio() {
    return document.querySelector("audio");
  }

  function playAudio(player, src) {
    player.volume = 1.0;
    if (player.getAttribute("src") !== src) {
      player.setAttribute("src", src);
    }
    player.play();
  }

  function showButton(button, opts) {
    if (opts.playing) {
      showPlayButton(button);
    } else {
      showPauseButton(button);
    }
  }

  function pauseAudio(player) {
    player.pause();
  }

  function manageAudio(player, opts) {
    if (opts.playing) {
      pauseAudio(player);
    } else {
      playAudio(player, opts.src);
    }
  }

  function playButton(button) {
    const player = getAudio();
    const playing = isPlaying(button);
    showButton(button, {
      playing
    });
    manageAudio(player, {
      playing,
      src: button.getAttribute("data-audio")
    });
  }

  function playButtonClickHandler(evt) {
    const button = getButtonContainer(evt.target);
    playButton(button);
  }

  const playButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".button");
  playButtons.forEach(function addHandler(el) {
    el.addEventListener("click", playButtonClickHandler);
  });
})();
```

```css
$color: #ff1818;
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: #353198;
  animation: fade 2s ease 0s forwards;
}

@keyframes fade {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.outer {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container.active {
  flex: 1 0 0;
  animation: fadebody 5s ease 0s forwards;
  background-size: 165px 165px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(teal 5px, #0000 5px), linear-gradient(90deg, teal 5px, #0000 5px), linear-gradient(black 10px, #0000 10px 160px, black 160px), linear-gradient(90deg, black 10px, #0000 10px 160px, black 160px), linear-gradient(orange 15px, #0000 15px 155px, orange 155px), linear-gradient(90deg, orange 15px, #0000 15px 155px, orange 155px), linear-gradient(black 20px, #0000 20px 150px, black 150px), linear-gradient(90deg, black 20px, #0000 20px 150px, black 150px), linear-gradient(teal 25px, #0000 25px 145px, teal 145px), linear-gradient(90deg, teal 25px, #0000 25px 145px, teal 145px), linear-gradient(black 30px, #0000 30px 140px, black 140px), linear-gradient(90deg, black 30px, #0000 30px 140px, black 140px), linear-gradient(orange 35px, #0000 35px 135px, orange 135px), linear-gradient(90deg, orange 35px, #0000 35px 135px, orange 135px), linear-gradient(black 40px, #0000 40px 130px, black 130px), linear-gradient(90deg, black 40px, #0000 40px 130px, black 130px), linear-gradient(teal 45px, #0000 45px 125px, teal 125px), linear-gradient(90deg, teal 45px, #0000 45px 125px, teal 125px), linear-gradient(black 50px, #0000 50px 120px, black 120px), linear-gradient(90deg, black 50px, #0000 50px 120px, black 120px), linear-gradient(orange 55px, #0000 55px 115px, orange 115px), linear-gradient(90deg, orange 55px, #0000 55px 115px, orange 115px), linear-gradient(black 60px, #0000 60px 110px, black 110px), linear-gradient(90deg, black 60px, #0000 60px 110px, black 110px), linear-gradient(teal 65px, #0000 65px 105px, teal 105px), linear-gradient(90deg, teal 65px, #0000 65px 105px, teal 105px), linear-gradient(black 70px, #0000 70px 100px, black 100px), linear-gradient(90deg, black 70px, #0000 70px 100px, black 100px), linear-gradient(orange 75px, #0000 75px 95px, orange 95px), linear-gradient(90deg, orange 75px, #0000 75px 95px, orange 95px), linear-gradient(black 80px, #0000 80px 90px, black 90px), linear-gradient(90deg, black 80px, #0000 80px 90px, black 90px), linear-gradient(teal, teal);
}


/* when container is active hide the svg */

.container.active .thePlay {
  display: none;
}

.button-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: auto;
  width: 582px;
  min-width: 582px;
  overflow: hidden
}

.inner-container {
  display: none;
}


/* when container is active hide the svg and show the inner container*/

.container.active .thePlay {
  display: none;
}

.container.active .inner-container {
  display: flex;
}

.container.active .inner-container.curtain {
  display: block;
}

.container.with-buttons.active .inner-container.curtain {
  display: flex;
}

@keyframes fadebody {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.playa,
.playb,
.playc {
  margin: auto 20px;
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.playa {
  fill: red;
  filter: drop-shadow(3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7));
}

.playb {
  fill: blue;
  filter: drop-shadow(3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7));
}

.playc {
  fill: orange;
  filter: drop-shadow(3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7));
}

.curtain {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 640px;
  margin: auto;
  flex: 1 0 0%;
}

.container.with-buttons .curtain {
  flex: none;
}

.panel-left,
.panel-right {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: calc(50% + 1px);
  /* rounding error fix */
  top: 0%;
  transition: all ease 10s;
  /*background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/600");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;*/
  overflow: hidden;
}

.panel-left {
  left: 0;
  /*background-color: rgb(91, 96, 106);*/
}

.panel-right {
  right: 0;
  /*background-color: rgb(229, 211, 211);*/
}

.panel-left::before,
.panel-right::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 200%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/id/26/1920/1080");
  background-size: auto;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0 0;
}

.curtain2 .panel-left::before,
.curtain2 .panel-right::before {
  background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/id/27/1920/1080");
}

.curtain3 .panel-left::before,
.curtain3 .panel-right::before {
  background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/id/27/1920/1080");
}

.panel-right::before {
  left: -100%;
}

.container.active .curtain .panel-left {
  animation: curtain1 8s forwards;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

@keyframes curtain1 {
  to {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}

.container.active .curtain .panel-right {
  animation: curtain2 8s forwards;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

@keyframes curtain2 {
  to {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}

@keyframes curtain3 {
  to {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}

.ratio-keeper {
  position: relative;
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 56.25%;
  border-radius: 25px;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.video-frame {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.playButton {
  position: relative;
  background-color: black;
  /*width: 150px; /* delete */
  margin: 2px;
  height: 195px;
  flex: 0 0 150px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 0 1px 2px black, inset 0 2px 2px -2px white, inset 0 0 2px 15px #47434c, inset 0 0 2px 22px black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 20px;
  perspective: 700px;
}

.playButton.active .button {
  transform: translateZ(20px) rotateX(25deg);
  box-shadow: 0 -10px 20px $color;
}

.playButton.active .button .light {
  animation: flicker 0.2s infinite 0.3s;
}

.playButton.active .button .shine {
  opacity: 1;
}

.playButton.active .button .shadow {
  opacity: 0;
}

.playButton .button {
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(1, 0, 1, 1);
  transform-origin: center center -20px;
  transform: translateZ(20px) rotateX(-25deg);
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  background-color: #9b0621;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: linear-gradient( darken($color, 25%) 0%, darken($color, 33%) 30%, darken($color, 33%) 70%, darken($color, 25%) 100%);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.playButton .button::before {
  content: "";
  background: linear-gradient( rgba(white, 0.8) 10%, rgba(white, 0.3) 30%, darken($color, 35%) 75%, darken($color, 45%)) 50% 50% / 97% 97%, darken($color, 20%);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  transform-origin: top;
  transform: rotateX(-90deg);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.playButton .button::after {
  content: "";
  background-image: linear-gradient(darken($color, 35%), darken($color, 45%));
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  transform-origin: top;
  transform: translateY(50px) rotateX(-90deg);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 50px 8px 0px black, 0 80px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.playButton .light {
  opacity: 0;
  animation: light-off 1s;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: radial-gradient( adjust-hue(lighten($color, 20%), 35), $color 40%, transparent 70%);
}

.playButton .dots {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: radial-gradient( transparent 30%, rgba(darken($color, 35%), 0.7) 70%);
  background-size: 10px 10px;
}

.playButton .characters {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(white, white) 50% 20%/5% 20%, radial-gradient( circle, transparent 50%, white 52%, white 70%, transparent 72%) 50% 80%/33% 25%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.playButton .shine {
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(1, 0, 1, 1);
  opacity: 0.3;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(white, transparent 3%) 50% 50%/97% 97%, linear-gradient( rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), transparent 50%, transparent 80%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)) 50% 50%/97% 97%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.playButton .shadow {
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(1, 0, 1, 1);
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(transparent 70%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8));
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

@keyframes flicker {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 0.8;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes light-off {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<audio></audio>

<div class="outer">

  <div class="container with-curtain">
    <svg class="playa thePlay" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
            <path d="M25.6,46.4L44.8,32L25.6,17.6V46.4z M32,0C14.3,0,0,14.3,0,32s14.3,32,32,32s32-14.3,32-32S49.7,0,32,0z
      M32,57.6C17.9,57.6,6.4,46.1,6.4,32S17.9,6.4,32,6.4S57.6,17.9,57.6,32S46.1,57.6,32,57.6z" />
        </svg>
    
    <div class="inner-container curtain curtain1">
      <div class="ratio-keeper">
        <div class="wrapa">
          <div class="video video-frame"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-left"></div>
        <div class="panel-right"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container with-curtain">
    <svg class="playb thePlay " width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
            <path d="M25.6,46.4L44.8,32L25.6,17.6V46.4z M32,0C14.3,0,0,14.3,0,32s14.3,32,32,32s32-14.3,32-32S49.7,0,32,0z
      M32,57.6C17.9,57.6,6.4,46.1,6.4,32S17.9,6.4,32,6.4S57.6,17.9,57.6,32S46.1,57.6,32,57.6z" />
        </svg>
    
    <div class="inner-container curtain curtain2">
      <div class="ratio-keeper">
        <div class="wrapb">
          <div class="video video-frame" data-id="2VwsvrPFr9w"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-left"></div>
        <div class="panel-right"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container with-buttons">
    <svg class="playc thePlay" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
      <path d="M25.6,46.4L44.8,32L25.6,17.6V46.4z M32,0C14.3,0,0,14.3,0,32s14.3,32,32,32s32-14.3,32-32S49.7,0,32,0z
      M32,57.6C17.9,57.6,6.4,46.1,6.4,32S17.9,6.4,32,6.4S57.6,17.9,57.6,32S46.1,57.6,32,57.6z" />
    </svg>
    
    <div class="inner-container button-container curtain curtain3">
      <div class="playButton b1" data-audio="http://getradio.me/svoefm">
        <div class="button">
          <div class="light"></div>
          <div class="dots"></div>
          <div class="characters"></div>
          <div class="shine"></div>
          <div class="shadow"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="playButton b2" data-audio="ttp:/fm1.hostingradio.ru:14536/rock90.mp3">
        <div class="button">
          <div class="light"></div>
          <div class="dots"></div>
          <div class="characters"></div>
          <div class="shine"></div>
          <div class="shadow"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="playButton b3" data-audio="http:/fm1.hostingradio.ru:14536/rock90.mp3">
        <div class="button">
          <div class="light"></div>
          <div class="dots"></div>
          <div class="characters"></div>
          <div class="shine"></div>
          <div class="shadow"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="playButton b4" data-audio="http:/fm1.hostingradio.ru:14536/rock90.mp3">
        <div class="button">
          <div class="light"></div>
          <div class="dots"></div>
          <div class="characters"></div>
          <div class="shine"></div>
          <div class="shadow"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="playButton b5" data-audio="http:/fm1.hostingradio.ru:14536/rock90.mp3">
        <div class="button">
          <div class="light"></div>
          <div class="dots"></div>
          <div class="characters"></div>
          <div class="shine"></div>
          <div class="shadow"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="playButton b6" data-audio="http:/fm1.hostingradio.ru:14536/rock90.mp3">
        <div class="button">
          <div class="light"></div>
          <div class="dots"></div>
          <div class="characters"></div>
          <div class="shine"></div>
          <div class="shadow"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="playButton b7" data-audio="http:/fm1.hostingradio.ru:14536/rock90.mp3">
        <div class="button">
          <div class="light"></div>
          <div class="dots"></div>
          <div class="characters"></div>
          <div class="shine"></div>
          <div class="shadow"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="playButton b8" data-audio="http:/fm1.hostingradio.ru:14536/rock90.mp3">
        <div class="button">
          <div class="light"></div>
          <div class="dots"></div>
          <div class="characters"></div>
          <div class="shine"></div>
          <div class="shadow"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="playButton b9" data-audio="http:/fm1.hostingradio.ru:14536/rock90.mp3">
        <div class="button">
          <div class="light"></div>
          <div class="dots"></div>
          <div class="characters"></div>
          <div class="shine"></div>
          <div class="shadow"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-left"></div>
      <div class="panel-right"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean with "don't work" - what is the issue?

Comment: There's nothing there when you click on the red and blue play, it's empty inside. Nothing appears when you click on the red or blue play image.

Comment: The curtain around the buttons is not aligned properly. for some reason. See image: https://i.imgur.com/CieEqLq.png

Comment: How is that fixed, the curtain is way off on the right side. https://i.imgur.com/Gzvrwg5.png